# Python - Regex - Match anything except

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to get my regular expression to work but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I am trying to find any file that is NOT in a specific format.  For example all files are dates that are in this format MM-DD-YY.pdf (ex. 05-13-17.pdf).  I want to be able to find any files that are not written in that format.

I can create a regex to find those with:

```
(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.pdf)
```

I tried using the negative lookahead so it looked like this:

```
(?!\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.pdf)
```

That works in not finding those anymore but it doesn't find the files that are not like it.

I also tried adding a .* after the group but then that finds the whole list.

```
(?!\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.pdf).*
```

I'm searching through a small list right now for testing:

```
05-17-17.pdf Test.pdf 05-48-2017.pdf 03-14-17.pdf
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: If your input string is `05-17-17.pdf Test.pdf 05-48-2017.pdf 03-14-17.pdf`, what would your desired output be from that string?

Comment: My desired output would be `Test.pdf 05-48-2017.pdf`.  It should find the second date too because it's written as 2017 and not 17 for the year.

Comment: @JakelC Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = "Test.docx 04-05-2017.docx 04-04-17.pdf secondtest.pdf"

new_data = re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+|\d{1,}-\d{1,}-\d{4}\.[a-zA-Z]+", s)
```

Output:

```
['Test.docx', '04-05-2017.docx', 'secondtest.pdf']
```

Comment: That might work for a particular set of input, but "file name is made up of letters  .pdf" is not the same requirement as "file name does not contain a date"

Comment: @khelwood Thank you for pointing that out. I will ask the OP to clarify.

Comment: Thank you!  That works for this situation.  Occasionally, there are other types of incorrect formatting such as `Jan-14-17.pdf` or `03-14-17 (2).pdf` or it's saved as a wrong filetype like `07-12-17.docx`. Is there any way to find anything that doesn't match the regex or do I need to just keep creating multiple different options seperated with the | key?

Comment: @JakeIC Glad to help. Please see my recent edit. I added a new test string to demonstrate the new feature.

Comment: Thank you!  So is there no way to find anything that doesn't match the regex?  There could be quite a few different ways someone could potentially enter in the date that I may not be able to guess.  If not I can always add or options as I go.

Comment: @JakeIC You are welcome! To be honest, I think the best way to capture anything that does not meet your original criteria is to write a regex to capture the dates that you do not want. What specific dates and patters would you consider "bad"?

Comment: @JakeIC to avoid false positive cases, it is easier to do a break-and-conquer. step 1: find everything that matches your exact patters. (use Ajax1234 answer) step 2:  compare it to the list of all existing files. step 3: spit out the difference with [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff).

Answer (score 0):

First find all that are matching, then remove them from your list separately. `firstFindtheMatching` method first finds matching names using `re` library:

```
def firstFindtheMatching(listoffiles):
    """
    :listoffiles: list is the name of the files to check if they match a format
    :final_string: any file that doesn't match the format 01-01-17.pdf (MM-DD-YY.pdf) is put in one str type output. (ALSO) I'm returning the listoffiles so in that you can see the whole output in one place but you really won't need that. 

    """
    import re
    matchednames = re.findall("\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\.pdf", listoffiles)
    #connect all output in one string for simpler handling using sets
    final_string = ' '.join(matchednames)
    return(final_string, listoffiles)
```

Here is the output:

```
('05-08-17.pdf 04-08-17.pdf 08-09-16.pdf', '05-08-17.pdf Test.pdf 04-08-17.pdf 08-09-16.pdf 08-09-2016.pdf some-all-letters.pdf')
set(['08-09-2016.pdf', 'some-all-letters.pdf', 'Test.pdf'])
```

I've used the main below if you like to regenerate the results. Good thing about doing it this way is that you can add more regex to your `firstFindtheMatching()`. It helps you to keep things separate.

```
def main():

    filenames= "05-08-17.pdf Test.pdf 04-08-17.pdf 08-09-16.pdf 08-09-2016.pdf some-all-letters.pdf"
    [matchednames , alllist] = firstFindtheMatching(filenames)
    print(matchednames, alllist)
    notcommon = set(filenames.split()) - set(matchednames.split())
    print(notcommon)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```